# Latex image not found

Tags: graphics, texniccenter, debugging

running `TeXnicCenter LaTex >> PDF` produces the following error:

```
LaTex warning: File 'Energy_Arc.png' not found.
```

Output shows empty box where image should be (with same error as above written inside it).

I have placed this png in C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter (I am assuming this is the build location).

As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134187/how-to-add-a-jpg-image-in-latex , the code I'm using is

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=90mm]{Capture1.png}
\caption{A simple caption}
\label{overflow}
\end{figure}
```

Output crashes when compiling Latex >> DVI (but only when attempting to actually view the image in output).

I have also tried the above with .jpg (no difference).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have placed this png in C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter (I am assuming this is the build location).

No. The file should be placed into the folder of your `.tex` document.

More generally, **no** user files belong in `C:\Program Files`. As the name says, this folder is for applications only. In a properly configured Windows this folder shouldn’t even be writeable for normal users without hassle.